# Python reading c typedef struct

Tags: python, c++, c, dll

Continue from my previous questions, I have tried out ctypes, struct and nametuple but I am still unable to get the data out. I manage to get it working if i import this dll file to my c++ program. It will be really helpful someone can help with this. Thank you very much!

c++ code

```
printf("Number: %s\n", NET_DVR_PLATE_INFO().sLicense);
```

c code

```
typedef struct tagNET_DVR_PLATE_INFO
{
    BYTE  byPlateType;                    
    BYTE  byColor;                        
    BYTE  byBright;                        
    BYTE  byLicenseLen;                    
    BYTE  byEntireBelieve;                
    BYTE  byRegion;                      
    BYTE  byCountry;                      
    BYTE  byArea;                         
    BYTE  byPlateSize;                    
    BYTE  byRes[15];                     
    char  sPlateCategory[MAX_CATEGORY_LEN/*8*/];
    DWORD dwXmlLen;                       
    char* pXmlBuf;                   
    NET_VCA_RECT    struPlateRect;       
    char sLicense[MAX_LICENSE_LEN];       
    BYTE byBelieve[MAX_LICENSE_LEN];    
}NET_DVR_PLATE_INFO, *LPNET_DVR_PLATE_INFO;
```

python code

```
hcnetsdk = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary(".\\HCNetSDK.dll")
class NET_DVR_PLATE_INFO(ctypes.Structure):
_fields_ = [
    ("byPlateType", ctypes.c_byte), 
    ("byColor", ctypes.c_byte), 
    ("byBright", ctypes.c_byte), 
    ("byLicenseLen", ctypes.c_byte),
    ("byEntireBelieve", ctypes.c_byte), #
    ("byRegion", ctypes.c_byte), 
    ("byCountry", ctypes.c_byte), 
    ("byArea", ctypes.c_byte), 
    ("byPlateSize", ctypes.c_byte), 
    ("byRes", ctypes.c_byte * 15), 
    ("sPlateCategory", ctypes.c_char * 8), 
    ("dwXmlLen", ctypes.c_short), 
    ("pXmlBuf", ctypes.c_char), 
    ("sLicense", ctypes.c_char * 16), 
    ("byBelieve", ctypes.c_byte * 16)]

def getPlateNumber():
    platenumber= NET_DVR_PLATE_INFO()
    y = hcnetsdk.platenumber.sLicense
    print(y)
```

I will get an error call

```
AttributeError: function 'platenumber' not found
```

Comment: What is the point of `platenumber= NET_DVR_PLATE_INFO()`, if you don't use it for anything?

Comment: What is throwing this error? What is your C++ code for your function? Prototype? Is it on Windows? If yes, is the symbol exported?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher For my C++ code, I will be getting a result of "Number: S1234B" which is a result from my hardware. but when i use it on python, I will have an error stating that the function is not found

Comment: That's why we need your C++ definition of your code (prototype and implementation). And platform.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher this is the line i am using on my C++ program printf("Number: %s\n", NET_DVR_PLATE_INFO().sLicense); All I need to do is to write this line after I have included the dll file. Yes, the program its running on windows platform

Comment: Please provide the FULL CODE that declares that function.